# How to align two different tables in codeigniter bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Say i have 2 different tables using bootstrap:

```
<table class="table">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Name:</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<table class="table">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Favorites:</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I'm using bootstrap, how can i make it so that both tables are aligned? Both tables only have 2 columns each. I would like the 2nd column to match vertically.
It's so random how wide they are.

So lets say the first table's 2nd column is aligned at the center of the page

but the 2nd table's 2nd column is so far right of the page.

[It looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVAqX.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can place both tables in a row, and then place each of the tables in their own container, giving each a class of `col-6`

Comment: But that would mean i have to change the grids of my page. It took me hours to figure this out. Is there a way to change it internally inside the table itself with the style attribute?

Answer (score 0):

using Bootstrap

```
  <table style="height: 100px;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="align-baseline">baseline</td>
      <td class="align-top">top</td>
      <td class="align-middle">middle</td>
      <td class="align-bottom">bottom</td>
      <td class="align-text-top">text-top</td>
      <td class="align-text-bottom">text-bottom</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

or you can use CSS

Comment: I'd rather not unless its not doable with bootstrap but im pretty certain it is.

I'm really bad with CSS especially since i only have notepad++ i can't see the changes CSS brings to my html in detail so it's a headache.

Comment: so use the bootstrap class

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, i solved it. Only needed to add Style attribute inside my Table divisions.

```
<table class="table">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="width:50%;">Name:</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<table class="table">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="width:50%;">Favorites:</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

now the 2nd column where all my variables i print out will align with each other.